# Qt Change label text from another class

Tags: c++, qt, text, qt-signals, slots

i'm trying to change the label text of Class A via Class B using Qt but i can't get it working, here's my codes:

*Class A:*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "loldata.h"

using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    LoLData *lold = new LoLData();

    QObject::connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(updateData()));
    QObject::connect(lold, SIGNAL(updatePlayerID(QString)), ui->label, SLOT(setText(QString)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::updateData()
{
    LoLData summoner;
    summoner.getSummonerData("Snylerr");
}
```

*Class A: (.h)*

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QObject>
#include <string>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void updateData();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

*Class B:*

```
#include "loldata.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

using namespace std;

int LoLData::getSummonerData(QString playerName)
{
    emit updatePlayerID("playerName");
    return 0;
}
```

*Class B: (.h)*

```
#ifndef DEF_LOLDATA
#define DEF_LOLDATA

#include <QApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <string>

class LoLData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    int getSummonerData(QString playerName);

signals:
    void updatePlayerID(QString playerName);

private:
};

#endif
```

You can see that i tried to use slots and signals but the text of the label is not changing, i saw a lot of examples on internet but i can't get them working
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `LoLData` here:

```
void MainWindow::updateData()
{
    LoLData summoner;
    summoner.getSummonerData("Snylerr");
}
```

This instance of `LoLData` named `summoner` is not connected to your label's `setText` slot.

`LoLData *lold = new LoLData();` - this instance of `LolData` is connected to you label's `setText` slot.

What should yo do? 
It depends on what you want to accomplish:

1. either connect your `summoner` instance to the label by inserting a `QObject::connect(&summoner...) inside your`updateData` method;
2. or you don't instantiate a new `LolData` variable and use `lold` inside your `updateData` function:

   `void MainWindow::updateData()
   {
       lold->getSummonerData("Snylerr");
   }`

Also in this case you have to put `lold` as a member variable.

Comment: It's working now, thanks you very much, you saved me !

Comment: It didn't change my MainWindow data.I think when i create new obj LoLData not existing object.

Answer (score 1):

In your MainWindow constructor, you connect your **lold** object to the setText slot.

But in updateData, you use an other object (summoner) which is not connect to anything. So when you use getSummonerData on summoner, the signal updatePlayerID is emitted nut they is no slot connected to it.